# Validate object property in Yup

Tags: javascript

a have object like this

```
const foo = {
 person: {
 name:"Jon",
 sex:"men"
}, 
 job: "drinker"
};
```

When i use `console.log(foo.person.name)` l got undefined. And can't validate my object

Question: how i can validate foo.person.name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional chaining and pre check if the value exists or not.

```
const foo = {
  person: {
    name: "Jon",
    sex: "men"
  },
  job: "drinker"
};
const name = foo?.person?.name ?? "Name is not available";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup is a schema builder for runtime value parsing and validation.
So defining the correct datatype is very crucial. In your case you are trying to define a object, so you can try something like:

```
  const obj = object({
  person: object({
        name: string().min(3).lowercase().trim() 
        sex: string().max(4).lowercase().trim()
        }),
      job: string().max(10) //add what validations you need
  })
  .json()
```

If you need further help with this you can go through [Yup Readme on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup?activeTab=readme)